# Juliaopt JuMP CbcSolver how to print progress

Tags: optimization, julia, julia-jump, coin-or-cbc

I coding in julia using JuMP of Juliopt.
I would like to know how to print the solve progress using CbcSolver?

I already used the log level parameter:
m = Model(solver = CbcSolver(log=1))

it works and you can choose between 0 to 3, higher more details.

but my problem is that the log level only prints after the solver finish, i already put the the time limit parameter "sec" but when it is set for higher values never stops and i don't know why!!

m = Model(solver = CbcSolver(sec=90,log=1))

I was going to try callbacks but Cbc does not support callback.

I am positive that there is a way to print because when i use the opensolver in excel a set Cbc to solve it shows the progress.I just dont know how to do this!!

Comment: This is probably an issue with the interface you're using to run Julia, not JuMP or Cbc itself. I've had this experience (output buffered until the end) with Jupyter, for example. If you run Julia from the terminal you should see the output live.

Comment: Perfect!!!! i was using atom! and when a used the console everything worked nicely!!!
Thanks very much!!!!